# Authorize Web Service Requests

Tags: c#, iphone, web-services, security

We have built numerous web services and hosted them on our internal servers and these will be used by our iPhone application. End users of the iPhone app need not sign into the application, they can just use the app without any credentials.

Whenever web services receive a request; I want to authorize that these requests are coming from iPhone app. How can i do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How safe do you want it to be ?

The dead simple and widely used technique is to require all webservice request include an ApiKey header. The server must then validate the ApiKey against a known list of allowed ApiKeys. If communication is done over SSL this is fairly safe (would require disassembly of the client code to find the key), on the other hand if communication is plain http, the ApiKey can be easily sniffed.

Comment: I've always wanted to ask this question :) -- and how might one go about sniffing like that?

Comment: @Mike, depends on where you are and how evil you are :-) 1) If you are on unencrypted WiFi, a packet sniffer will allow you to read all unencrypted TCP traffic. 2) If you are on the same local network (wired) in the same subnet, you can also use the packet sniffer 3) If you have access to a router along the paths of the traffic, traffic is easy to sniff. Different types of WiFi encryption offers various degrees of security, but can in general be broken.

Comment: @driis, Thanks! I guess i can try using ApiKey and SSL. How about oAuth? Is it useful in these scenarios? Also can you point me to resources explaining best practices for implementing APiKey store.